# How to find the measure of an angle?

Tags: geometry

I have a triangle with the following angles:

- 84 degrees,
- x + 59,
- and x + 51.

x + 51 is angle A

I have to find angle A's measure.

Since the interior angles of a triangle add up to be 180 degrees, I set up the equation like so:

`x + 59 + x + 51 + 84 = 180` My equation

`2x + 194 = 180` add like terms

`2x = -19` subtract 194 from both sides of the equation

`x = -7` divided both by 2x to get x alone

It has occurred to me that I am finding x here (it still makes no sense to get a negative number) but this is the only equation I know to set up.

Notes:

This is for geometry homework and I realize just asking you to solve my problems is academically dishonest off topic if I have not put genuine effort into the question, which I have (put effort in, that is). I have put a lot of mental effort into figuring this out, though, so I will tell you what I did and hopefully you can tell me where I went wrong and how to correct my mistake, because I think it is obvious I made one. For the record I accidentally deleted my math notes from my iPad and Googling the question this morning produces hard to understand results. My geometry teacher was unavailable while I was working last night due to my lack of internet connection.

Comment: Note that it doesn't matter that $x$ is negative as long as the angles themselves are positive.

Comment: @Nicholas Though I am not trying to find `x` but rather the measure of angle A.

Comment: And the measure of angle $A$ is?

Comment: @Nicholas Your comment just now have me a eureka moment. I spent so much time fretting over the negative number (I usually don't deal with negatives too often) that I forgot to as the saying goes "plug in" x. The sad part is I spent an hour thinking this through last night, which makes me feel like an idiot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

84+x+59+x+51 = 180 so x=-7 therefore angles are -7+51=44 which is A and -7+59=52 Thus angles are 84,44,52. NOTE x isn't a angle so dont get confused all angles are positive here. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I came to that conclusion after reading the comment by @Nicholas. I forgot the "plug it in" step.

Comment: Your welcome!..

Answer (score -1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gD1gg.jpg)

Just ı want to learnd what the x and how did you do

Comment: I don't now have can ı find x ı fınd 51but is not correct